# Split and filter dataset in SSR Report

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, reportbuilder

I have a report where I need to display only the selected order/line/release from a screen, I already sent the string to the RDL with the selected values but I'm not sure how to filter it in the report.

In this example I sent three orders each order is separated by a ~ and the SO/Line/Rel is separated by a |:

104996|2|1~105216|1|1~107564|1|1 (string sent to the RDL file)

- 104996|2|1~  SO|Line|Rel
- 105216|1|1~  SO|Line|Rel
- 107564|1|1   SO|Line|Rel

How can achieve this? I know custom code or functions can be used but I'm new with SSRS and I'm not sure how to implement this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If I understand you correctly, I would suggest that you parse those values into separate columns in your query before sending data to the RDL.  Its just easier.

Comment: Are you trying to send these values by appending them to the report URL or some other method?